# A better way to do it in Pandas, I have 2 loops

Tags: python, pandas

New to Pandas ; is there a better way to do that ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO

devices = StringIO("""name;date;CPU;Freq;Voltage
RPI;201501;arm;700MHz;5V
Galileo;201501;intel;400MHz;3.3V
UNO;201502;atmel;16MHz;5V
""")
d = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(devices, sep=';', index_col=None)

comments = StringIO("""comment;t1;t2;t3
cool;arm;;
great!;atmel;;
great!;intel;5V;
fun;atmel;16MHz;
fun;700MHz;atmel;
""")
c = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(comments, sep=';', index_col=None)

n = d.copy()
n['cool'], n['great!'], n['fun'] = 0, 0, 0

for i, row in n.iterrows():
    for j, com in c.iterrows():
        if np.all(np.in1d(np.array(com[['t1', 't2', 't3']].dropna()), np.array(row))):
            n.loc[i, c.loc[j, 'comment']] = 1
```

At the end, I build that new DataFrame n, and it looks like that:

```
    name    date    CPU     Freq    Voltage     cool    great!  fun
0   RPI     201501  arm     700MHz  5V          1       0       0
1   Galileo 201501  intel   400MHz  3.3V        0       0       0
2   UNO     201502  atmel   16MHz   5V          0       1       1
```

The other df, d and c look like that

```
    name    date    CPU     Freq    Voltage
0   RPI     201501  arm     700MHz  5V
1   Galileo 201501  intel   400MHz  3.3V
2   UNO     201502  atmel   16MHz   5V

    comment     t1      t2      t3
0   cool        arm     NaN     NaN
1   great!      atmel   NaN     NaN
2   great!      intel   5V      NaN
3   fun         atmel   16MHz   NaN
4   fun         700MHz  atmel   NaN
```

I have to use 2 loops to do it. That breaks my dream of Pandas!
Anything better? must be missing something..

Comment: Could you explain in words how you want to join the dataframes c and d ?

Comment: d is a dataframe of devices, with some components (CPU, Freq and Voltage). c is a dataframe of comments and each comment is link to some tags. i.e. if a device has "atmel', it will be great!. If it has "intel and 5V" it will get the comment great! too. There are several ways to get the same comment.

Comment: Did you want the 700 Mhz to be in the t1 column, in 'c' or was it by mistake ?

Comment: yes, 700MHz is in t1. They are tags, so, no order. Actually, I should have named t1, t2, ... -> tag1, tag2, .. That's why I used that np.in1d and np.all. Convienient! But I feel like using those loops are not "pandas". And it's slow (my actuall dataset is much larger :) )

Answer (score 0):

```
c['val'] = 1

comments = pd.pivot_table(c,index='t1',columns='comment',
                            values='val',aggfunc=sum).fillna(0)

df = pd.merge(d,comments,left_on='CPU',right_index=True,how='left')
```

comments:

```
comment  cool  fun  great!
t1                        
700MHz      0    1       0
arm         1    0       0
atmel       0    1       1
intel       0    0       1
```

df:

```
      name    date    CPU    Freq Voltage  cool  fun  great!
0      RPI  201501    arm  700MHz      5V     1    0       0
1  Galileo  201501  intel  400MHz    3.3V     0    0       1
2      UNO  201502  atmel   16MHz      5V     0    1       1
```

Comment: thanks, but Galileo cannot get great! Because to do so, it should have both 'intel' and '5V'. But I will check your idea to see if I can get to the solution!